# How to Optimize Simple Circular/Rotating Buffer/FIFO Handling for Performance

Tags: c, rotation, queue, buffer, circular-buffer

Hi: I have been ramping up on C and I have a couple philosophical questions based on arrays and pointers and how make things simple, quick, and small or balance the three at least, I suppose.

I imagine an MCU sampling an input every so often and storing the sample in an array, called "val", of size "NUM_TAPS". The index of 'val' gets decremented for the next sample after the current, so for instance if val[0] just got stored, the next value needs to go into val[NUM_TAPS-1].

At the end of the day I want to be able to refer to the newest sample as x[0] and the oldest sample as x[NUM_TAPS-1] (or equivalent).

It is a slightly different problem than many have solved on this and other forums describing rotating, circular, queue etc. buffers. I don't need (I think) a head and tail pointer because I always have NUM_TAPS data values. I only need to remap the indexes based on a "head pointer".

Below is the code I came up with. It seems to be working fine but it raises a few more questions I'd like to pose to the wider, much more expert community:

- Is there a better way to assign indexes than a conditional assignment
  (to wrap indexes < 0) with the modulus operator (to wrap indexes >
  NUM_TAPS -1)? I can't think of a way that pointers to pointers would
  help, but does anyone else have thoughts on this?
- Instead of shifting the data itself as in a FIFO to organize the
  values of x, I decided here to rotate the indexes. I would guess that
  for data structures close to or smaller in size than the pointers
  themselves that data moves might be the way to go but for very large
  numbers (floats, etc.) perhaps the pointer assignment method is the
  most efficient. Thoughts?
- Is the modulus operator generally considered close in speed to
  conditional statements?  For example, which is generally faster?:

offset = (++offset)%N;
*OR**
offset++;
if (NUM_TAPS == offset) { offset = 0; }

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_TAPS     10
#define STARTING_VAL  0
#define HALF_PERIOD   3

void main (void) {

  register int sample_offset = 0;
  int wrap_offset = 0;
  int val[NUM_TAPS];
  int * pval;
  int * x[NUM_TAPS];
  int live_sample = 1;

  //START WITH 0 IN EVERY LOCATION
  pval = val; /* 1st address of val[] */
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { *(pval + i) = STARTING_VAL ; }

  //EVENT LOOP (SAMPLE A SQUARE WAVE EVERY PASS)
  for (int loop = 0; loop < 30; loop++) {
    if (0 == loop%HALF_PERIOD && loop > 0) {live_sample *= -1;}
    *(pval + sample_offset) = live_sample; //really stupid square wave generator

    //assign pointers in 'x' based on the starting offset:
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { x[i] = pval+(sample_offset + i)%NUM_TAPS; }

    //METHOD #1: dump the samples using pval:
    //for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { printf("%3d ",*(pval+(sample_offset + i)%NUM_TAPS)); }
    //printf("\n");

    //METHOD #2: dump the samples using x:
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { printf("%3d ",*x[i]); }
    printf("\n");

    sample_offset = (sample_offset - 1)%NUM_TAPS; //represents the next location of the sample to be stored, relative to pval
    sample_offset = (sample_offset < 0 ? NUM_TAPS -1 : sample_offset); //wrap around if the sample_offset goes negative
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cost of a % operator is the about 26 clock cycles since it is implemented using the DIV instruction. An if statement is likely faster since the instructions will be present in the pipeline and so the process will skip a few instructions but it can do this quickly.

Note that both solutions are slow compared to doing a BITWISE AND operation which takes only 1 clock cycle. For reference, if you want gory detail, check out this chart for the various instruction costs (measured in CPU Clock ticks)
http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

**The best way to do a fast modulo on a buffer index is to use a power of 2 value for the number of buffers so then you can use the quick BITWISE AND operator instead.**

```
#define NUM_TAPS     16
```

With a power of 2 value for the number of buffers, you can use a bitwise AND to implement modulo very efficiently. Recall that bitwise AND with a 1 leaves the bit unchanged, while bitwise AND with a 0 leaves the bit zero.

So by doing a bitwise AND of NUM_TAPS-1 with your incremented index, assuming that NUM_TAPS is 16, then it will cycle through the values 0,1,2,...,14,15,0,1,...
This works because NUM_TAPS-1 equals 15, which is 00001111b in binary. The bitwise AND resulst in a value where only that last 4 bits to be preserved, while any higher bits are zeroed.

So everywhere you use "% NUM_TAPS", you can replace it with "& (NUM_TAPS-1)". For example:

```
#define NUM_TAPS 16
...
//assign pointers in 'x' based on the starting offset:
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) 
    { x[i] = pval+(sample_offset + i) & (NUM_TAPS-1); }
```

Here is your code modified to work with BITWISE AND, which is the fastest solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_TAPS     16  // Use a POWER of 2 for speed, 16=2^4
#define MOD_MASK     (NUM_TAPS-1) // Saves typing and makes code clearer
#define STARTING_VAL  0
#define HALF_PERIOD   3

void main (void) {

  register int sample_offset = 0;
  int wrap_offset = 0;
  int val[NUM_TAPS];
  int * pval;
  int * x[NUM_TAPS];
  int live_sample = 1;

  //START WITH 0 IN EVERY LOCATION
  pval = val; /* 1st address of val[] */
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { *(pval + i) = STARTING_VAL ; }

  //EVENT LOOP (SAMPLE A SQUARE WAVE EVERY PASS)
  for (int loop = 0; loop < 30; loop++) {
    if (0 == loop%HALF_PERIOD && loop > 0) {live_sample *= -1;}
    *(pval + sample_offset) = live_sample; //really stupid square wave generator

    //assign pointers in 'x' based on the starting offset:
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { x[i] = pval+(sample_offset + i) & MOD_MASK; }

    //METHOD #1: dump the samples using pval:
    //for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { printf("%3d ",*(pval+(sample_offset + i) & MOD_MASK)); }
    //printf("\n");

    //METHOD #2: dump the samples using x:
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAPS; i++) { printf("%3d ",*x[i]); }
    printf("\n");

    // sample_offset = (sample_offset - 1)%NUM_TAPS; //represents the next location of the sample to be stored, relative to pval
    // sample_offset = (sample_offset < 0 ? NUM_TAPS -1 : sample_offset); //wrap around if the sample_offset goes negative

    // MOD_MASK works faster than the above
    sample_offset = (sample_offset - 1) & MOD_MASK;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> At the end of the day I want to be able to refer to the newest sample as x[0] and the oldest sample as x[NUM_TAPS-1] (or equivalent).

Any way you implement this is very expensive, because each time you record a new sample, you have to move all the other samples (or pointers to them, or an equivalent).  Pointers don't really help you here.  In fact, using pointers as you do is probably a little more costly than just working directly with the buffer.

My suggestion would be to give up the idea of "remapping" indices *persistently*, and instead do it only *virtually*, as needed.  I'd probably ease that and ensure it is done consistently by writing data access macros to use in place of direct access to the buffer.  For example,

```
// expands to an expression designating the sample at the specified
// (virtual) index
#define SAMPLE(index) (val[((index) + sample_offset) % NUM_TAPS])
```

You would then use `SAMPLE(n)` instead of `x[n]` to read the samples.

I might consider also providing a macro for adding new samples, such as

```
// Updates sample_offset and records the given sample at the new offset
#define RECORD_SAMPLE(sample) do { \
    sample_offset = (sample_offset + NUM_TAPS - 1) % NUM_TAPS; \
    val[sample_offset] = sample; \
} while (0)
```

With regard to your specific questions:

> - Is there a better way to assign indexes than a conditional assignment (to wrap indexes < 0) with the modulus operator (to wrap
>     indexes > NUM_TAPS -1)? I can't think of a way that pointers to
>     pointers would help, but does anyone else have thoughts on this?

I would choose modulus over a conditional every time.  Do, however, watch out for taking the modulus of a negative number (see above for an example of how to avoid doing so); such a computation may not mean what you think it means.  For example `-1 % 2 == -1`, because C specifies that `(a/b)*b + a%b == a` for any `a` and `b` such that the quotient is representable.

> - Instead of shifting the data itself as in a FIFO to organize the values of x, I decided here to rotate the indexes. I would guess that
>     for data structures close to or smaller in size than the pointers
>     themselves that data moves might be the way to go but for very large
>     numbers (floats, etc.) perhaps the pointer assignment method is the
>     most efficient. Thoughts?

But your implementation *does not* rotate the indices.  Instead, it *shifts* pointers.  Not only is this about as expensive as shifting the data themselves, but it also adds the cost of indirection for access to the data.

Additionally, you seem to have the impression that pointer representations are small compared to representations of other built-in data types.  This is rarely the case.  Pointers are usually among the largest of a given C implementation's built-in data types.  In any event, neither shifting around the data nor shifting around pointers is efficient.

> - Is the modulus operator generally considered close in speed to conditional statements? For example, which is generally faster?:

On modern machines, the modulus operator is *much* faster on average than a conditional whose result is difficult for the CPU to predict.  CPUs these days have long instruction pipelines, and they perform branch prediction and corresponding speculative computation to enable them to keep these full when a conditional instruction is encountered, but when they discover that they have predicted incorrectly, they need to flush the whole pipeline and redo several computations.  When that happens, it's a lot more expensive than a small number of unconditional arithmetical operations.